# Can i call a .js file from html file (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodemailer

I have a little bit of a problem with an email function. I tried 'nodemailer' package and it worked when I wrote the code in a .js file. When i called the .js file (node emailfile.js) it worked and I received an email (code below).

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  secure: false,
  port: 25,
  auth: {
    user: 'MYUSERNAME', // this is not an error, I don't want to share my data
    pass: 'ok1994ka'
  },

  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});

let HelperOptions = {
  from: '"Sportot App" <fiziohome@gmail.com>',
  to: 'fiziohome@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Hello World',
  text: 'Good day to you!'
};

transporter.sendMail(HelperOptions, (error, info) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.log("error");
  }
  console.log("Epasts aizsūtīts");
});
```

Now, what I want to do is call this .js file from my HTML file.

```
<button ion-button block color="danger" (click)=pasts()>Sūtīt e-pastu</button>
```

And in my html file inside  tags I inserted:

```
<script src="email.js"></script>
```

And inserted a line "function pasts(){"inside there is the whole code from email.js file"}". I hope you can understand my question and somebody of you got answer to this. Thank you!

Comment: I cannot speak about AngularJS since I've never used it. However, it appears as though you are trying to run node.js code (ECMAScript Javascript) in the browser. Unless AngularJS makes that possible, the browser cannot use node modules, such as nodemailer. Instead, you will need to submit any user input from a client-side HTML form to the node server before node can then transmit the email using nodemailer.

Comment: https://blog.upstate.agency/how-to-send-an-email-using-angular-sails-js-and-mailgun-95226ad51064

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to call that code directly from the browser. You will need to host that file on a webserver and from Angular you will need to make a http request to the webserver running node.

You need to understand which parts of a web application are client and which parts are server. The Angular app is downloaded by the browser and runs on the client machine. The node side of the application runs on the server and Angular makes requests to the server via http.

There is more to this can can be explained in a Stack Overflow answer as there are many parts to answering how to set this up.